# FakeMessageContext throws NullReferenceException

Tags: rebus

I'm trying to write unit test for my saga. I have used SagaFixture to host my Saga and using FakeBus. I have also used FakeMessageContext because, in a Saga exectution I'm using MessageContext to get return address.

Now, when I'm trying to call Handle method on Fixture, it throws exception of type NullReferenceException.

Pasting code below:

SearchSaga

```
public class SearchSaga : Saga<SearchSagaData>, IAmInitiatedBy<PersonRequested>, IHandleMessages<PersonSearchCompleted>
{
    public void Handle(PersonRequested message)
       {
            Data.Id = new Guid(message.MessageId);
            Data.ReturnAddress = MessageContext.GetCurrent().ReturnAddress;
            Bus.Publish(message);
        }

}
```

SagaUnitTest

```
[Test]
        public void PublishResponseOfTypeSearchPersonRequest()
        {
            var bus = new FakeBus();
            var saga = new SearchSaga(bus);
            var fixture = new SagaFixture<SearchSagaData>(saga);
            FakeMessageContext.Reset();
            var fakeContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMessageContext>();
            fakeContext.Stub(s => s.ReturnAddress).Return("queuename");
            fakeContext.Stub(s => s.Headers).Return(new Dictionary<string, object>());

            // act
            using (FakeMessageContext.Establish(fakeContext))
            {
                fixture.Handle(new PersonRequested {MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Query = "Abc"});
            }
            var sentRequests = bus.PublishedMessages.OfType<SearchPersonRequest>().ToList();
            Assert.That(sentRequests.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
```

Error Stacktrace:
   at Rebus.SagaContext..ctor(Guid id)
   at Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.DispatchToHandler[TMessage](TMessage message, IHandleMessages`1 handler)   at Rebus.Testing.SagaFixture`1.Handle[TMessage](TMessage message)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by the fact that your `IMessageContext` mock has a `null` value on the `Items` property. The thrown exception is just pretty bad, but I'll make sure that the reported error gets better in the future.

For now, you can fix the situation by setting up a an items dictionary like so:

```
fakeContext.Stub(s => s.Items).Return(new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

Moreover, instead of using `MessageContext.GetCurrent()` to get to the message context inside your handler, you should take advantage of the fact that all Rebus' IoC container adapters ensure that you can have an `IMessageContext` injected into all of your handler instances.

This way, there's no need to use `FakeMessageContext` in your unit tests.

Comment: Followed your suggestion and got into next issue. I have Bus.Publish in my saga, and at that point, it throws following exception:

System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IMessageContextProxy9e54bc5d128e47338ab8b9cdfaabd032' to type 'Rebus.MessageContext'.
   at Rebus.MessageContext.get_MessageDispatchAborted()
   at Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.Dispatch(TMessage message)   at Rebus.Testing.SagaFixture`1.Handle(TMessage message)

Comment: Ah yes, I see - seems I didn't foresee that `FakeMessageContext` could be used around a message handler. I edited my answer with a way to work around this

Comment: not too much sure about correctness of my code, though it worked. need your views. Not sure about code in default constructor
`private readonly IBus _bus;
        private readonly IMessageContext _messageContext;

        public IBus Bus
        {
            get { return _bus; }
        }

        public SearchSaga()
        {
            _bus = RebusHost.Adapter.Bus;
            _messageContext = MessageContext.GetCurrent();
        }

        public SearchSaga(IBus bus, IMessageContext messageContext)
        {
            _bus = bus;
            _messageContext = messageContext;
        }`